# Enable field after checked checkbox in yii2

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

[image]

I have attached image and code.Here I wanna, after checked checkbox enable that field ow it will be disable.Actually I am not able to understand how to get id of check box because in yii2 and simple html code it's different i am using simple html code for check box and other field in yii2 format...Thanks in advances

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-inline" >
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="checkbox" id="Airshipment" name="Airshipment" value="A" selected>By Air
<!-- 
                <?=$form->field($modelAirshipment, 'air_ship_id')->checkBox(['label' => 'By Air', 'uncheck' => null, 'checked' => 'checked']); ?>
           -->
           </div>
           </div> 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <?= $form->field($modelAirshipment, 'air_mawbno')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <?= $form->field($modelAirshipment, 'air_pieces')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <?= $form->field($modelAirshipment, 'air_packing_type')->dropDownList([ 'Box' => 'Box', 'Drum' => 'Drum', ], ['prompt' => '']) ?>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-inline">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Seashipment" name="Seashipment[S]" value="S" selected>By Sea
        </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
             <?= $form->field($modelSeashipment, 'sea_packing_type')->dropDownList([ 'Box' => 'Box', 'Drum' => 'Drum', ], ['prompt' => '']) ?> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
            <?= $form->field($modelSeashipment, 'sea_pieces')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
             <?= $form->field($modelSeashipment, 'sea_dimension')->textInput() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I doubt `php` is playing any part in this example.. Please share `parsed` HTML

Comment: I have attached code in that only checkbox line in html code

Answer (score 1):

i got this problem before , i solve it by `hide` and `show` elements by JS code  :)

in `window.onload` make all elements `.hide` except the check boxes, on checked make the elements you need `.show`